# Installing and running Redmine while having two different Ruby versions installed

Tags: ruby, redmine

We are planning to deploy Redmine on one of our Ubuntu servers. Unfortunately, Redmine will only run with Ruby 1.8 installed.
The problem is that our server is already running Ruby 1.9 which is required by several applications.

Two questions:

1. Can Redmine be set up for using a special Ruby version (i.e., linking two Ruby 1.8 in config file(s))?
2. In general: Do you see any problems in having two Ruby versions installed on system and linked to /usr/bin  ?

Thanks for your time and help, appreciate!

Best wishes,
Bionicman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use rvm if you want to have multiple rubies installed.  [rvm](https://rvm.io)

With rvm installed, it is not difficult to run multiple applications on different ruby versions.  With one caveat: phusion passenger can only run on one ruby at a time.  But if, for example, your existing apps are running on passenger on 1.9.2, you can still run a mongrel for redmine on the same server running 1.8.7.  Pretty much everything you need to know is on the page linked, above.

Comment: rvm is great. We've had good success using reverse proxies in apache to point to other web services to make them all appear like they're on the one web server. Also, keep an eye out for the "chiliproject" fork of redmine, they've been talking about ruby 1.9 compatibility for a while: https://www.chiliproject.org/boards/1/topics/107

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! rvm sounds really promising!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a self contained Redmine installation try our [BitNami Redmine stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine). It is free all-in-one installer that will do exactly what you want (it bundles its own Ruby runtime, required libraries, etc)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396391/anything-speaking-against-the-bitnami-org-ruby-rails-redmine-stack